# How do you check that a vim command (a motion) succeeded or failed?

Tags: vim

I wanted to do something like this

```
try
  normal! t_
catch
  normal! w
endtry
```

meaning that it will go the next underscore `_` or to the next word boundary if there is no underscore.

How do you actually check if a motion was successful? I was think to compare the `getpos('.')` before and after the command but I realized that doesn't necessarily mean that the motion was unsuccessful. For example if the cursos was already before the `_`

Comment: why not check the text from cursor pos till the end of line, if it containing a `_`, if yes, do sth. else, do sth. else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best shot will be to keep current position (setting a mark or saving current position) before motion and check position after that.

```
:mark a
# or
:let col = col(".")
:let line = line(".")
# motion command (say w,j,zj,f.)
# check difference
:echo col("'a") . "," . line("'a") . " = " . col('.') . "," . line('.')
# or
:echo col . "," . line . " = " . col('.') . "," . line('.')
```

Documentation:

- [col() function](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#col())
- [line() function](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#line())

Depending on your needs, `col()` maybe omitted as a movement detector.

More accurate position can be obtained with `getpos()`:

> getpos({expr}) Get the position for {expr}.  For possible values of {expr} see |line()|.
>         The result is a |List| with four numbers:
>
> ```
>       [bufnum, lnum, col, off]
> ```

Documentation

- [getpos() function](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#getpos())

```
:mark a
# or
:let old_pos = getpos(".")
# motion command (say w,j,zj,f.)    
:let mark_a = getpos("'a")
:let current_pos = getpos(".")
# check difference
:echo mark_a[2] . "," . mark_a[1] . " = " . current_pos[2] . "," . current_pos[1]
# or
:echo old_pos[2] . "," . old_pos[1] . " = " . current_pos[2] . "," . current_pos[1]
```

check real usage, with save for old mark if it is already used (lnum > 0), here:

[ag.vim autoload/ag.vim:215](https://github.com/albfan/ag.vim/blob/master/autoload/ag.vim#L215)

Comment: you don't have to add a mark. Simply store the previous cursor position and compare with the later cursor position

Comment: Damn it! You're right. That's even simpler. I will add a note about that.